# I created a custom watch face app. How to open the project which I created after installation?

Tags: wear-os

I am new to Android wear app development. I created a custom watch face app and it is successfully installed in my android wear emulator. But I am not in the position to run that app.My app is not in the "settings->Change watch face". Where the project is stored in the android wear emulator?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

    <service
        android:name=".MyAnalogHand"
        android:label="@string/my_analog_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/analog_hand" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

Comment: Are you sure it was installed? Make sure it's listed in `adb shell pm list packages -3`. If it is, but it's not appearing in the list of watch faces, then the system isn't recognizing it as a watch face. Please post the manifest element for your `WatchFaceService` subclass, and we might be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: What does your res/xml/analog_hand.xml look like?